# TogetherJS and HTML Object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, togetherjs

I have a simple page that displays an external site. I want to be able to share my page (with the external site) using TogetherJS. I cannot change the source of my external site so use an object to display it. This displays as expected - but the cursor sharing is only for the HTML outside of the HTML Object/external site. Is it possible to do this without changing the source of the embedded page?

```
<HTML> 
    <HEAD> 
        <script src="https://togetherjs.com/togetherjs-min.js"></script> 
    </HEAD> 
    <BODY> 
        <button onclick="TogetherJS(this); return false;">Start Collaborating</button> 
        <BR> 
        <BR> 
        <object type="text/html" data="http://mypage.com" style="width:90%; height:90%"> </object> 
    </BODY> 
</HTML>
```

John

Comment: Try to use iframe like "<iframe src="http://mypage.com" style="width:90%; height:500px" />"

Comment: It doesnt work with iframe either. TogetherJS wont show the iframe contents

Comment: What's the problem here, `object` is an element of html5 and it does not load content from the url you added. But it does by `iFrame`. But bad luck, `togetherjs` not support iframe.